# tab completion for service command on debian

Tags: debian, bash

I have two systems with debian squeeze installed. On one system when I type:

```
service <TAB>
```

it shows me all available service (from /etc/init.d)

on the other system it shows me all files from the current directory. Does anyone know which setting changes that behaviour ?

UPDATE:

The file /etc/bash_completion.d/service was missing. I copied it from the machine where it is working. If I type `complete -p | grep service` it shows me:

```
complete -F _service service
```

On the machine where it is not working that command shows me nothing. I executed `complete -F _service service` in the command line, after that, the command `service <TAB>` shows me:

```
service -su: completion: function `_service' not found
```

this function is defined in the service file I recently copied, for some reasons it can't be found ...

Comment: Do you have `/etc/bash_completion.d/service` file present?

Comment: The file wasn't there, I've added it, but it's still not working. I've seen with complete -p I can display all bindings, on the machine where  it is working it shows me a lot of binding, where it's not working it displays nothing. I think it doesn't bind for some reason the files in /etc/bash_completion.d ...

Answer (score 21):

First of all check if bash-completion is installed run:

```
 $ dpkg -l bash-completion | tail -1
```

it should output something like:

```
ii  bash-completion  1:1.3-1  programmable completion for the bash shell
```

If output is empty thus install it with:

```
aptitude install bash-completion
```

Then check if it is enabled:

```
 $ grep -A 2 bash_completion ~/.bashrc /etc/bash.bashrc
```

Should output something like

```
~/.bashrc:if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
~/.bashrc:    . /etc/bash_completion
~/.bashrc:fi
```

If nothing like this or it is commented (has `#` after `~/.bashrc:`) then add/uncomment

```
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
fi
```

to ~/.bashrc and reread it with

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

After that it should work fine.

Comment: bash completion works on both machines, but different. if I type service <TAB> it shows me all services on one machine, on the other one the files of the current directory.

Comment: Are versions of `bash-completion` the same?

Comment: same debian versions, some bash-completion

Comment: one difference is on server 1 I'm directly on the console, an server 2 I'm connected via ssh.

Comment: Directory completion is NOT bash_completion, which is an ugly hack perpetrated by Debuntu on the readline library (which is what shells use to ...read...lines). bash_completion is NOT enabled on the second box.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, but "tab" only showed two of the many services.
Looking at /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion you can see:

```
_sysvdirs()
{
    sysvdirs=( )
    [[ -d /etc/rc.d/init.d ]] && sysvdirs+=( /etc/rc.d/init.d )
    [[ -d /etc/init.d ]] && sysvdirs+=( /etc/init.d )
    # Slackware uses /etc/rc.d
    [[ -f /etc/slackware-version ]] && sysvdirs=( /etc/rc.d )
}
```

in my case, /etc/rc.d/init.d existed and had only two services.
After removing that dir, everything worked fine.